# Wordpress - Find CSS-Source (maybe generated)

Tags: css, file, search

I am currently working on a website built with wordpress and the the7 theme. Now there is a css file loaded/generated, I can't seem to find. Do you have any suggestions, how to find it, so I can edit it? The devtools just show me the code, so I guess it is generated by the theme, but I can't tell for sure. It actually does not load, if I change the start page but if I deactivate every single part of the page, containing content, it still loads, which confuses me a bit.

Thank you very much for your advice!

[image]

Comment: Have you noticed that the domain is `fonts.googleapis.com`? It is a remote css file hosted by google, you won't be able to find it in your own files. Maybe try to search your files for `Open Sans` to find which line of code loads it. But it may be loaded from a database entry so you may not find it in the files themselves. So you can't edit it, but you should be able to overload classes by a css file loaded afterwards or with a more precise set of CSS rules

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Well I thought too, that it might come from the database, but I wasn't able to find the entry there yet. I actually wanted to eliminate the call to google completely, due to gdpr reasons. I thought, if I just overwrote the css rule, it might still make the call. Will try it later, when I find the time though.

Comment: What bothers you about the call for GDPR? It's pretty standard to load a remote font from Google (or another font host). As long as you make sure no private info is added to the call to Google you should be fine

Comment: What bothers me, is that the call to google to receive the font, sends the IP-adress which is not okay according to gdpr afaik.

Comment: The IP adress should be fine if no other info such as the user pseudonym / name is added to the call, or else 99% of the web would violate GDPR

Comment: What the font...suddenly it's working fine...Can't tell you, why but it works like a charm..Thank you for your time..

Comment: It was probably the theme or a plugin, good luck for the rest

Answer (score 0):

Did some maintenance work like updating the theme and activating/deactivating plugins and now it seems to work..